# prolog meaning of ([(X,_)|T], X)

Tags: list, prolog, unification

So, I have the following phrases

```
dX([(X,_)], X).
dX([(X,_)|T], X):- dX(T, R),
                X > R,
                !.

dX([_|T], R):- dX(T, R).
```

I get the meaning of the first one, which means if 1st item of the list is X, return X no regardless of the second item. But i struggle with understanding the last two. Please help if you know what they mean.

Comment: You've got the meaning of the first clause just a little bit wrong. It doesn't mean *... if the **1st** item of the list is `X`...* it means *If the first argument is a list consisting of just one element, `(X, _)`...*

Comment: Not just one, it means if the first element of the list is X, then return X no matter what the second element is

Comment: But `[(X,_)]` is a list of just one element, and that element is `(X,_)`. So ti is just one. You have your interpretation of the first predicate clause incorrect.

Comment: Here's how you can read the second predicate. Note that the naming `dX` isn't very descriptive. So we'd read it, *`X` has a `dX` relation to `[(X,_)|T]` if `R` has a `dX` relation to `T`, and `R > X`*. The cut prevents backtracking in the event that `R > X` succeeds, so Prolog won't further explore further solution at that point (*e.g.*, the 3rd clause).